# if then statement that allows me to have a price of a 4th selection be based on a, b, or c, selected

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="checkbox" name="KingBed" id="KingBed" />
<input type="checkbox" name="queenbed" id="queenbed" />
<input type="checkbox" name="FullBed" id="FullBed" />
<input type="checkbox" name="headboard" id="headboard" />


check = document.getElementById("headboard").checked;
if(check) { maxTotal += 25 /*PRICE*/; minTotal += 17/*PRICE*/; }
```

I am looking for an if then statement that if bed1 is chosen, then when headboard is chosen, it will issue one set of prices, but if queenbed, and so forth is chosen, it will list another price.

Comment: Are you aware that Java and JavaScript are not the same thing?

Comment: I don't believe that check boxes are appropriate for the UI here. How about a `select` control for the bed model and a `select` control for the headboard model? That option would also make your required code simpler.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take it in a different direction:

```
<div>
    <h1>Buy a new bed now!</h1>
    <p>
        <label for="size">Size</label><br />
        <select id="size">
            <option value="twin">Twin</option>
            <option value="full">Full</option>
            <option value="queen">Queen</option>
            <option value="king">King</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="headBoard">Head Board</label><br />
        <select id="headBoard">
            <option value="none">None</option>
            <option value="modelA">Model A</option>
            <option value="modelB">Model B</option>
            <option value="modelC">Model C</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="button" onclick="buy()" value="Buy!" />
    </p>
</div>
```

Then include the following JavaScript

```
var pricing = {
    size: {
        twin: 100,
        full: 200,
        queen: 300,
        king: 400
    },
    headBoard: {
        none: 0,
        modelA: 100,
        modelB: 200,
        modelC: 300
    }
};

function buy() {
    var sizeSelection = document.getElementById("size").value,
        headBoardSelection = document.getElementById("headBoard").value,
        sizePrice = pricing.size[sizeSelection],
        headBoardPrice = pricing.headBoard[headBoardSelection],
        grandTotal = sizePrice + headBoardPrice;
    alert("Grand Total: $" + grandTotal.toFixed(2));
}
```